# vscode 1.10.2 -> Cannot launch debug target in terminal

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I have an app in node.js running fine in VsCode 1.8

Now, after a few weeks we are trying to execute it on VsCode 1.10.2 (with F5 key) and I got this error:

[image]

> Cannot launch debug target in terminal (Cannot convert undefined or
>   null to object).

We have tried to remove this line or changed its contents:

```
    "console": "externalTerminal"
```

Any idea?  Is it a bug?

Comment: I have also created an issue on github vscode.
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22997

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for this bug, as it is said here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22997#issuecomment-288518411

[image]